# Redirect http url to https - Godaddy + Google sites

Tags: dns, hosting, google-sites, godaddy-api

I have godaddy domain which is pointing google sites. "Https" link is working fine for my website but "http" is not working:

https://www.beautivago.com (Working)

http://www.beautivago.com (Not Working)

Comment: Both are working here. I see that your site redirect to https.

Comment: its not working without www. Its sending me at old site

https://beautivago.com/

Comment: You better test from different networks first. I see that your both www and non www are working.